# Swift, How can I connect 2 classes to 1 scene in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 classes, MainViewController and ButtonHandler.  I want to be able to handle most of the UI and control in the mainViewController. But since the application will have a lot of buttons I was hoping to make a ButtonHandler class so that I could abstract the button aspect of the UI from the MainViewController.  Button handler would include a lot of buttons and handle actions to do when the buttons are clicked.

The problem lies in that I also want to be able to add 1 button or 2 in my MainViewController class.  So if set the MainViewController class in the view/scene, then I can add buttons to MainViewController, but I can't add buttons to the ButtonHandler and vice-versa.

If my ButtonHandler class inherits my MainViewController class, then I could add buttons to both of them, which is what I wanted.  But is there another way?  I was thinking inheritance wouldn't really show a proper relationship between the 2 classes.

Is there a way to connect/set 2 classes into 1 scene/view in storyboard?

Comment: You can add a generic "object" into a scene from the object palette and set its class to `ButtonHandler`.  If the customisation is specific to the button then you could also subclass `UIButton` and use those button subclasses in your scene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your `ButtonHandler` looks something like this:

```
class ButtonHandler: NSObject {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("button tapped")
    }
}
```

## In your storyboard, search for "object" component panel panel (bottom right of screen):

[image: Search for object]

## Drag that component to the scene panel (left in storyboard). Select the object from the scene panel and change the class of the object in the top, right panel:

[image: Change the object class]

You can now connect the button outlets to those of the `ButtonHandler`.

You can also create an outlet to a `ButtonHandler` in your `UIViewController` and access the handler from code.